# Как вывести списки через print c чередованием?

Tags: python, массивы, сортировка

Как вывести списки через print c чередованием?
Два списка:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

вывести нужно:

1

4

2

5

3

6

7

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6, 7]



n = len(a)
c = len(b)


if c>n:
    y=0
    for i in b:
        
        try:
            print(a[y])
            y = 1+y
        except:pass
        print(i)
else:
    y=0
    for i in a:
        
        try:
            print(b[y])
            y = 1+y
        except:pass
        print(i)
```

P.S не ругайте за качество кода. Писалось максимально просто для понимания )

Comment: во-первых, код ужасен до невозможности. во-вторых: не следует отвечать на вопросы, нарушающие правила сайта.